# Java successfully installed but eclipse won't launch

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded and installed java runtime envirement. Then i checked it using the java verification tool and it says that it's successfully installed but eclipse still won't work and alerting that a java runtime envirement or java development kit is required to run eclipse.

Java verification tool result:

[image: Java verification result]

Eclipse launcher error:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 8.1! i think it's clear from the window style

Comment: Try the 32 bit version of Java and make sure that the 32 bit version is the first one in your path.

Comment: I'm a Windows 7/Mac user.  Windows 8 is, if anything, visually much different.

Comment: What does your PATH look like?

Comment: What you mean by (PATH look like) what PATH?

Comment: Open a command prompt and do `echo %PATH%`.

Comment: Here is it (Sorry i have removed some non related lines wifi and other stuffs) http://pastebin.com/FCV0d31K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this line to eclipse.ini

```
-vm 
D:/work/Java/jdk1.6.0_13/bin/javaw.exe  <-- change to your JDK actual path
```

But it's worth setting JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME anyway.

Comment: Tanks it's workin after editing the PATH and installing the right java version.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with an Eclipse based IDE. My problem was that I installed the 64 bit version when that IDE required the 32 bit version of Java.

Answer (score -2):

Try re-install eclipse?

I know that it happens with Textpad (the text editor I use for Java) that you must install the JRE+JDK **before** you install the text editor otherwise it'll have trouble finding the path, not sure about Eclipse but it might solve the problem

Comment: Eclipse is not installable! you unzip an copy it to the programs directory.